# MAPI - reduce CPU usage during QueryRows & FindRow calls

Tags: c++, winapi, outlook, mapi

As the title states, is there a way or a method to reduce CPU usage during mail iteration?

Even if i neglect any memory allocations(`std::wstring`'s initialization) with the `SRowSet::aRow[Index].lpProps[Index].Value.lpszW` member, CPU jumps to 30%

Purpose of this thread is to utilize a better working flow to load a huge chunk of mails and save them on a disk with an efficient resources (memory / CPU) usage.

Current flow:

```
SizedSPropTagArray(10 ,MailPropsTagArray) = {
        10, { PR_SENDER_NAME_W, PR_DISPLAY_TO_W, PR_DISPLAY_CC_W,
        PR_DISPLAY_BCC_W, PR_SUBJECT_W, PR_BODY, PR_ENTRYID, PR_PARENT_DISPLAY_W, PR_PARENT_ENTRYID, 0x1035001f }
    };

    if(FAILED(hr = spContentsTable->SetColumns(
        (SPropTagArray*)&MailPropsTagArray, TBL_BATCH)))
    {
        return;
    }

    if(FAILED(hr = spContentsTable->SortTable(
        &setSortOrder_, TBL_BATCH)))
    {
        return;
    }

    spContentsTable->SeekRow(BOOKMARK_BEGINNING, 0, nullptr);

    while(SUCCEEDED(hr = spContentsTable->FindRow(
        spSRestriction_.get(), BOOKMARK_CURRENT, 0)))
    {
        while (MAPI_E_BUSY == hr)
        { 
            if (MAPI_E_BUSY == (hr = spContentsTable->QueryRows(1, 
                0, ppRows)))
            {  
                 if (MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT != (hr = spTable->WaitForCompletion
                   (0 , 1000 , nullptr))) 
                     hr = MAPI_E_BUSY;
            }
        }
        std::wstring strSenderName = ppRows->aRow[0].lpProps[0].Value.lpszW
    }
```

Edit: Msg's store creation

```
ATL::CComPtr<IMsgStore> spStore;
    if(FAILED(hr = spSession->OpenMsgStore(0, spBinaryStoreHeader->cb,
        (LPENTRYID)spStoreSet->aRow[i].lpProps[0].Value.bin.lpb, nullptr, MDB_WRITE | MDB_NO_MAIL | MDB_NO_DIALOG, &spStore)))
    {
        LOG(ERR) << "Failed opening msgStore";
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually get MAPI_E_BUSY from FindRow? What store provider are you using? Is there a particular reason you are using TBL_BATCH?

Comment: I have modified my code regarding the message store issue, i think. i haven't recieved any MAPI_E_BUSY error, but heard it's a good practice to check for that. i've not implemented any AdviseSink mechanism to catch async messages, thats why im using TBL_BATCH rather than TBL_ASYNC

Comment: If you don't use the  TBL_ASYNC, all the calls will be synchronous.